# What is this huge bat-winged creature?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, star-wars-jedi-fallen-order

While watching a trailer for *Star Wars Jedi: Fallen Order*, I saw this interesting creature that I do not recognise:

[image: bat-winged unknown creature, way taller than a man]

**What is it?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [StarWars.com](https://www.starwars.com/news/new-star-wars-jedi-fallen-order-trailer-highlights), this is **Gorgara**. (emphasis mine)

> There are some new creatures introduced in the trailer, and in proper Star Wars tradition, they’re big. Very big. The **bat-like chirodactyl** is known as “**Gorgara**,” it was revealed today. And Cal’s joyride on the creature — and later battle with it — seems like some instant-classic Star Wars gaming.
> <sub>source: [6 Highlights from the new Star Wars Jedi: Fallen Order Trailer](https://www.starwars.com/news/new-star-wars-jedi-fallen-order-trailer-highlights)</sub>

[Chirodactyl](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chirodactyl) is the creature's species. Gorgara would be the name given to this individual creature.

> Chirodactyls were a species of winged carnivorous creature. One chirodactyl known as Gorgara became infamous within legend.
> <sub>source: [Chirodactyl](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chirodactyl)</sub>

... and from the Star Wars Databank:

> Local legends tell of a fearsome winged beast that scours the deepest crags for prey, latches onto its target with a fierce grip, and soars to dizzying heights on powerful wings. This apex predator is known as Gorgara "the winged daemon of the canyon," and she will deceive her prey before attacking.
> <sub>source: [Gorgara the Chirodacty](https://www.starwars.com/databank/gorgara-the-chirodactyl)</sub>

Gorgara' reported gender is female.

[image]

---

<sub>The first linked article was written by Dan Brooks, Lucasfilm’s senior content strategist of online and the editor of [StarWars.com](https://www.starwars.com).</sub>